# How do I automatically generate static HTML from HAML with Sinatra or Padrino?

Tags: sinatra, rendering, haml, padrino

I want to serve static HTML pages using `nginx`.  Then, I will use `jQuery` to update DIVs, SPANs, etc via AJAX calls from a Padrino server.

I like creating my web pages in HAML because it's easier but in production, I don't want to serve HAML templates.  Just raw, HTML at the speed of nginx.

Is there an easy way to do this?

What would be ideal would be a service that automatically renders HAML, partials, etc into the public folder that nginx could serve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple,

add padrino-cache to your app

```
class SimpleApp < Padrino::Application
  register Padrino::Cache
  enable :caching

  get '/foo', :cache => true do
   expires_in 30 # expire cached version at least every 30 seconds
   'Hello world'
  end
end
```

Then save wherever you want to serve it:

```
set :cache, Padrino::Cache::Store::File.new(Padrino.root('public'))
```

You can read more here: http://www.padrinorb.com/guides/padrino-cache

Answer (score 1):

First thing that pops to my mind would be [Jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll). Anyway I see it only as a matter or optimization, so if you already have a Sinatra, you could start by rendering HAML on every request, and than add caching.