# How do I render a static haml template in padrino?

Tags: ajax, sinatra, haml, padrino

I want to do essentially the same thing: [How do I automatically generate static HTML from HAML with Sinatra or Padrino?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236456/how-do-i-automatically-generate-static-html-from-haml-with-sinatra-or-padrino)

This answer didn't quite go far enough for me.  After I have caching setup, how would I send a particular haml file to the client?

E.g.

```
get '/foo', :cache => true do
    expires 30
    haml '/templates/foo.haml'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serve any file in `templates` you could do something like:

```
get '/*', :cache => true do |name|
    expires 30
    haml "/templates/#{name}.haml"
end
```

and they will all be cached.